# Convert from `ObservableEmitter` to `Observer` in rx-java2

Tags: rx-java2

Is there a easy way to convert from `io.reactivex.ObservableEmitter<T>`to `io.reactivex.Observer<T>`? I could not find function to do that in `rx-java2` library.

The implementation seems to be trivial:

```
 public static <T> Observer<T> toObserver(ObservableEmitter<T> oe) {
    return new Observer<T>() {

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            oe.setDisposable(d);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(T t) {
            oe.onNext(t);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            oe.onError(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            oe.onComplete();
        }
    };
}
```

but it feels that it should be part of standard library implementation, as it provides transformation between two core types in `rx-java2`.

Basically I am trying to migrate following code from rxjava 1 to 2

```
class X<T, O1, O2> implements Transformer<T, Either<O1, O2>> {

Transformer<T, O1> t1;
Transformer<T, O2> t2;

@Override
public Observable<Either<O1, O2>> call(Observable<T> input) {
    return input.flatMap(new Func1<T, Observable<Either<O1, O2>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Either<O1, O2>> call(final T t) {
            return Observable.<Either<O1, O2>>create(new OnSubscribe<Either<O1, O2>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(final Subscriber<? super Either<O1, O2>> sub) {
                    t1.call(Observable.just(t)).map(o1 -> Either.<O1, O2>left(o1)).subscribe(sub);
                    t2.call(Observable.just(t)).map(o2 -> Either.<O1, O2>right(o2)).subscribe(sub);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

Notice that `OnSubscribe` provides `Subscriber` interface which I can then use to subscribe to two other `Observable's`, with rxjava 2 conversion is needed.

Comment: There is no such thing in the standard library because why would you even do this? If you want to "subscribe" your emitter to an `Observable`, you actually should subscribe directly to that `Observable`. If you create your `Observable` on subscription, use `defer()` instead of `create`.

Comment: I have two transformers `ObservableTransformer<T, O1> t1` and  `ObservableTransformer<T, O2> t2` and I want to combine them into `ObservableTransformer<T, Either<O1, O2>>`. In apply method of result transformer I `flatMap` with function that calls `Observable.create` for each `T`. `Observable.create` takes `ObservableOnSubscribe` with `ObservableEmitter` and I want to subscribe that `emitter` to results of `t1` and `t2`. In rxjava 1 `subscribe` would accept same `Subscriber` interface.

Comment: Yes, I can use defer and simplify above code... Thanks @akarnokd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need `publish(Function)`:
(Your code looks convoluted and was violating the protocol in v1 by the way).

```
ObservableTransformer<T, O1> t1 = ...
ObservableTransformer<T, O2> t2 = ...

ObservableTransformer<T, Either<O1, O2>> combiner = o -> 
    o.publish(g -> Observable.merge(
        t1.apply(g).map(o1 -> Either.<O1, O2>left(o1)),
        t2.apply(g).map(o2 -> Either.<O1, O2>right(o2))
    ));
```

If you really want to stick to the outer `flatMap` (in case the inners go async), use `merge()` instead of `create`:

```
return input.flatMap(new Func1<T, Observable<Either<O1, O2>>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Either<O1, O2>> call(final T t) {
        Observable<T> just = Observable.just(t);
        Observable.merge(
            t1.call(just).map(o1 -> Either.<O1, O2>left(o1)),
            t2.call(just).map(o2 -> Either.<O1, O2>right(o2))
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, `publish(Function)` is what was needed. And yeah the code was convoluted. Minor corrections to your answer `Func1` is no longer there and `Observable.wrap` call is needed on `t1.apply(g)`. It is also possible to create observable with `Observable.just` and then `flatMap` it with identity function, would you say `merge` is preferable for this?

Comment: Oops, just looked at the source code of `merge` and this is how it is implemented with `fromArray` followed by `flatMap` :)